# AFrame: How to put THREE.LineBasicMaterial in Aframe

Tags: javascript, three.js, aframe

I am working on putting LineBasicMaterial in AFrame but have stumbled into some problems:

## 1. Variables are somehow injected into the schema and cannot be taken out without errors

I have a box:

```
<a-box material="shader: linebasic;"></a-box>
```

And have registered a custom shader:

```
AFRAME.registerShader('linebasic', {
    schema: {
        blending:       {default: THREE.NormalBlending},
        color:          {type: 'color', default: 0xffffff, is: 'uniform'},
        depthTest:      {default: true},
        depthFunc:      {default: THREE.LessEqualDepth},
        depthWrite:     {default: true},
        fog:            {default: false},
        linewidth:      {default: 10},
        linecap:        {default: 'round'},
        linejoin:       {default: 'round'},
        needsUpdate:    {default: true},
        opacity:        {default: 1},
        side:           {default: THREE.FrontSide},
        transparent:    {default: true},
        vertexColors:   {default: THREE.NoColors},
        visible:        {default: true}
    },
    init: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        delete data.flatShading;
        this.material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial(data);
        this.update(data);
    },
    update: function (data) {
        this.material.clone(data);
    }
});
```

Somehow data.flatShading has been set even though the object and shader do not have it on them. That's why I `delete data.flatShading`.

Another property that is also in data is `shader`. If I delete it, the console gives me this error message:

> components:material:error Unknown shader schema undefined +0ms

If I leave it in, I get a notice message:

> THREE.LineBasicMaterial: 'shader' is not a property of this material.

So either way something's wrong apparently.

## UPDATE of #1:

The following fixes #1 as @ngokevin posted:

```
AFRAME.registerShader('linebasic', {
    schema: {
        blending:       {default: THREE.NormalBlending},
        color:          {type: 'color', default: 0xffffff, is: 'uniform'},
        depthTest:      {default: true},
        depthFunc:      {default: THREE.LessEqualDepth},
        depthWrite:     {default: true},
        fog:            {default: false},
        linewidth:      {default: 10},
        linecap:        {default: 'round'},
        linejoin:       {default: 'round'},
        needsUpdate:    {default: true},
        opacity:        {default: 1},
        side:           {default: THREE.FrontSide},
        transparent:    {default: true},
        vertexColors:   {default: THREE.NoColors},
        visible:        {default: true}
    },
    init: function (data) {
        data = AFRAME.utils.extend({}, data);
        delete data.flatShading;
        delete data.shader;
        this.material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial(data);
        this.update(data);
    },
    update: function (data) {
        this.material.clone(data);
    }
});
```

## 2. LineBasicMaterial shows as a solid white block

Even though I'm using THREE.LineBasicMaterial with **all** of its properties and a lot of the properties of THREE.Material the material does not show up as lines, but as a solid block.

Material and LineBasicMaterial do not have 'wireframe' so I don't know how to make this work without just adding wireframe in and 'hacking' LineBasicMaterial.

Number 2 is most important to me right now, but I also would like to fix 1. I think they are related, therefor I put them in one question

Comment: can you just add wireframe and will it work?

Comment: Nope. it gives me this:
`three.js:20406THREE.LineBasicMaterial: 'wireframe' is not a property of this material.`
So I guess LineBasicMaterial doesn't use wireframe but IS a wireframe shader.

Comment: Your linewidth is 10, that seems pretty thick?

Comment: Tried 0, 1... 10. Nothing happens

Comment: Could it be that AFRAME.registerShader is a wrapper for ShaderMaterial instead of RawShaderMaterial and somehow disallows the use of the actual THREE.js shaders?

Comment: And if you have any spare time: https://xaddict.me/vr/

Comment: registerShader has a shortcut to ShaderMaterial with vertexShader/fragmentShader...but that's not used if you are just using LineBasicMaterial. Also is the LineBasicMaterial meant to be used with THREE.Line, maybe you have to work it with that?

Comment: right!!!! that's probably it. It probably only shows results on lines

Answer (score 1):

For #1, since that is currently passing a direct access to the `data` object, you shouldn't delete it, but instead clone it and then delete. There is an issue on file to simply do `this.data` rather than receiving it as a function.

```
data = AFRAME.utils.extend({}, data);
```

Comment: That fixed #1. I will update the code. #2 still isn't working though.